# Persistent in-memory objects in Django

Tags: python, django, chatbot, in-memory, django-channels

I'm trying to build a chatbot using Django and for this I need to keep some object in memory that preserves the state. I'm using Django and Django-channels for build this application, however, for every request it creates a new object from a database and I can't find any way to preserve the state. Any advice?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should _not_ save state in memory. You should save it in the session or save it in the database linked to the current session/user.

Comment: My state is rather big. It's an entire ML-based model. How can I store it in session?

Comment: Sounds like a separate (background) service to me. Django is for web services not for ML.